# Mysterious layout bug in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, layout

Sorry for pictures, but this bug appears randomly, I can't provide jsFiddle code, because I don't know how to reproduce it.

Here is part of my site that looks good in major browsers:
[image: Valid layout]

Usually it looks good in Chrome, but sometimes I am getting this layout:

[image: Invalid layout]

This bug appears on all site pages, not just this sample page.

When I try to open development tools and change some layout, bug is eventually dissapear on entire site and I can't reproduce it until make few browser reloads.

I also know that it is old Chrome bug, it is exists at least one year, so I believe that somebody already know solution how to fix it.

Please help me, any help is appreciated.

P.S. I have "clean" browser, without extensions. Other people also see this bug, not only me:).

P.P.S. If somebody want to reproduce this bug - you can follow <strike>**site**</strike> (link removed at request) that you see on pictures, but as I told before - it appears sometimes, if it's not appear, close and open browser and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect a FOUC that isn't corrected by a final reflow when finally the font used by this menu is downloaded and available.

Items are styled with the 'SignikaNegativeBold' font. This font is loaded with `@font-face` in the third CSS file. That's very late, try to load it ASAP  before any image or other resource, at the beginning of the first CSS file. Only `@import` declarations should be written before that because well otherwise it won't work.

Also try to load only one CSS file, by merging your different CSS files into one (you should continue to work with many CSS files, just merge them on the server into one new file that will be downloaded by users).

Unrelated: you declare `<html lang="ru" (...)>` but it appears as english to me, I can't read cyrillic ;) You should dynamically change the declared language in a multilingual website. `en` for english pages, `ru` for russian ones, etc

Comment: I implement this and checked again, it really works! Thank you so much __FelipeAls__, I didn't know about this @font-face feature. You really save a lot of my life time.